# Creating a .p12 file

Tags: openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

Using `openssl`, I've created a private key as follows:

```
openssl genrsa -out myKey.pem
```

Then, to generate the `csr` demanded by the CA, I've executed the following:

```
openssl req -new -key myKey.pem -out cert.csr
```

The CA responded with a certificate which I stored in a file named `myCert.cer`

I'd now like to bundle the necessary components (private key, public key(?) and certificate) into a single `.p12`. To do so I've run the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in myCert.cer
```

but I'm getting the following error message:

```
No certificate matches private key
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Btw if someone wants to sign the `cert.csr` hisself, then one could use `openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -signkey key.pem -out cert.crt` and then `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey key.pem -out cert.p12`. No need to use the additional command from the answer.

Comment: How is the .cer generated, mentioned in the question above?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The `openssl` [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#) says that file supplied as the `-in` argument must be in **PEM** format.

Turns out that, contrary to the CA's manual, the certificate returned by the CA which I stored in `myCert.cer` is not **PEM** format rather it is **PKCS7**.

In order to create my `.p12`, I had to first convert the certificate to **PEM**:

```
openssl pkcs7 -in myCert.cer -print_certs -out certs.pem
```

and then execute

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in certs.pem
```

Comment: what is "myKey.pem"? which file is it?

Comment: That's the one that has the private key; see the beginning of the question.

Comment: Best explanation step by step of how to create a p12 file. Thanks for it!

Comment: What does certs.pem include? Both public and private key?

Comment: Just the certificate (public key)

Comment: certs.pem should ideally be the fullchain pem instead of just the issued cert pem so you won't get issues with intermediate / root CA not being provided.

Comment: in my case i don't had a myKey.pem file, my private key file was created as .key file, so if it's your case too use `openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey private_key.key -in certs.pem`

Comment: If your p12 is rejected with incorrect password (apple tools), try legacy format with `-legacy`

Answer (score 46):

I'm debugging an issue I'm having with SSL connecting to a database (MySQL RDS) using an ORM called, [Prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma). The database connection string requires a PKCS12 (.p12) file (if interested, described [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql)), which brought me here.

I know the question has been answered, but I found the following steps (in Github [Issue#2676](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2676)) to be helpful for creating a .p12 file and wanted to share. Good luck!

1. Generate 2048-bit RSA private key:

   `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`
2. Generate a Certificate Signing Request:

   `openssl req -new -sha256 -key key.pem -out csr.csr`
3. Generate a self-signed x509 certificate suitable for use on web servers.

   `openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key key.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem`
4. Create SSL identity file in PKCS12 as mentioned here

   `openssl pkcs12 -export -out client-identity.p12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem`

Comment: Apparently, when it asks you to enter a password on the 4th command, you're supposed to literally type "password", and then confirm by typing it again. I must be missing something...

Comment: @KevinBeal from my understanding, the password it requests is the password used to secure the PKCS12 file. You get to create the password. If someone wanted to open and inspect the PKCS12 file, you would need the password to access the file, I believe.

Comment: In step 3, I was given the option to choose a password. If that's the password you're referring to, it didn't work at all. [This link](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options) appears to show that the password is "password". But I know almost nothing about it.

Comment: You can be prompted for a password up to twice. If the input key file requires one you will be prompted for that, then you will be prompted for the password to set on the output `.p12` file. You can avoid the prompt for the latter with `-passout` and the former with `-passin`, see openssl-passphrase](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-passphrase-options.html) docs for details (tl;dr `-passout pass:"your password here"`).

Comment: openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key key.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem
`Warning: No -copy_extensions given; ignoring any extensions in the request`