# Solace Client Authentication gives untrusted certificate error (Response Code: 401)

Tags: ssl, client-certificates, solace

I am getting Untrusted Certificate error (Response Code: 401) with Solace Client Certificate Authentication Scheme.

Here are the details over configurations made:
- Created a self-signed server and client certificates in pem format (With Private Keys)
- Uploaded both to Certs folder on solace VMR
- Configured server certificate to be used as Server Certificate on Solace VMR
- Added client certificate to the trusted-root (Configure/authentication) trusted-root
- From the client setting below properties over session object (On top of other required properties):
    objSessionProperties.SSLClientCertificateFile 
    objSessionProperties.SSLClientPrivateKeyFile
    objSessionProperties.SSLClientPrivateKeyFilePassword

By making above things, I can call Create Session successfully, whereas it leads to an exception while connecting to the session. Here is the error information received from Solace: 
{(Subcode=LoginFailure, Error string=Untrusted Certificate, Response code= 401 )}

Thanks for your help in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "Untrusted Certificate" login failure error indicates that the appliance rejected the client because it does not trust the client's certificate provided in "SSLClientCertificateFile". You should verify that the certificate authority (CA) certificate of the CA that signed your client certificate is configured on the appliance as a trusted root certificate.

Comment: I am getting this issue with the self signed certificate. I have added the CN name to the SSLTrustedCommonNameList property as well added the client certificate to the trusted-root file on the Solace VMR. Is there any other configuration required here?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the client on Java was creating .p12 file as needed for the property SSL Key Store Format (see this [page](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/API-Developer-Guide/Defining-Client-Authentication.htm#Client-Cert)). To get p12 file you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141215/creating-a-p12-file)

Next step was setup my properties:

**keystore-location=/{path}/keyStore.p12**, where the *path* - from the root

**keystore-password-location=configuration/fileWithPasswordForP12File.properties** to provide password to decode the data from *keyStore.p12* file

After this properties took affect you can get 403 error: 403 Client Certificate Authentication is Shutdown

To resolve it you you need to configure the server certificate for every VNP from Solace (see [doc](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-Client-Authentication.htm#Client-Cert)) this way:

`solace(configure)# message-vpn <vpn-name>`

`solace(configure/message-vpn)# authentication`

`solace(configure/message-vpn/authentication)# oauth`

`solace(...gure/message-vpn/authentication/oauth)# no shutdown`

You can verify current user's certificate content from Solace UI:

System->UserMgmt->User Authentication->{select user from Client Certificate Authority Name}->Edit->Change Certificate

This content must match the decoded data in keyStore.p12 and uploaded certificate on solace server from the folder ***/usr/sw/jail/certs***