# How can i obtain .p12 certificate for firebase cloud messaging from apple macbook keychain

Tags: firebase, react-native, macos, apple-push-notifications

I have difficulties with generating the proper certificate, I have created the certificate in the apple developer console by following these steps:

1. I have created a certificate signing request (first without key pair, then with key pair encoded with SHA 2000 size)
2. I have created an apple certificate in the developer console and downloaded it to the disk.
3. I double-clicked the certificate to add it to the keychain, and when I click on the certificate there is red text that this certificate is not trusted
4. I right-click and select export, then select a file format and the .p12 option is unavailable for me.
   What do I need to generate a .p12 file, this format is required by firebase.

Thanks

Comment: You need to include the private key as well as the certificate. If you import the private key into your keychain, it *might* properly associate that with the cert and let you create the .p12 using the pair, or you can do it from the files with the `openssl` command (see [this](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141215/creating-a-p12-file)).