# How to create PKCS12 From PEM file and Key File

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, keytool

I am new to configure SSL certification.
I have following file.

- root.pem
- intermediate.pem
- domain.pem
- domain.key

I want to PKCS12 with four files using OPENSSL tool.
I search many things but I did not get it. Can you please help me how to generate PKCS12 using above 4 files.

Comment: Copy all the certificates (the PEM files) into one PEM file, you can simply append them. And then use the second command of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144736/150978